# MAC OS Xcode Swift 2.2 Fullscreen Mode

Tags: macos, swift2, viewcontroller

What Swift code will switch the app to fullscreen?
I found references with example code for IOS. 
I am looking for a code which works for a MacOS app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to override `viewDidAppear` in `NSViewController`:

```
class ViewController : NSViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        let presOptions: NSApplicationPresentationOptions = ([.FullScreen,.AutoHideMenuBar])   
        let optionsDictionary = [NSFullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions :
            NSNumber(unsignedLong: presOptions.rawValue)]
        self.view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.mainScreen()!, withOptions:optionsDictionary)
        self.view.wantsLayer = true
        }
}
```

↳ [Apple Developer API Reference : viewDidAppear()](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstitlebaraccessoryviewcontroller/1397780-viewdidappear)

Answer (score 10):

Updated for Swift 4

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    let presOptions: NSApplication.PresentationOptions = [.fullScreen, .autoHideMenuBar]
    let optionsDictionary = [NSView.FullScreenModeOptionKey.fullScreenModeApplicationPresentationOptions: presOptions]
    view.enterFullScreenMode(NSScreen.main!, withOptions: optionsDictionary)
    view.wantsLayer = true
}
```

Comment: This opens full screen modes nicely,  but I note that when I put a label into the view, the label does not appear. Same with buttons. Why?

Comment: same issue showing the black window.  Any solution?

Answer (score 3):

An alternative, if you want different behavior, where the menu bar is available when you move your mouse to top is this. However, it starts out as a normal size window then grows, so that may not be desirable depending on what you are doing.

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    view.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
}
```

Comment: That's much better answer, because in the accepted one the aplication in fullscreen locks everything in MacOS, you can't resize thw window, there is no menu bar appearing and even Command + Tab keys won't work! If you change system volume the indicator won't display either!

Comment: How can I exit to full screen? with a button in the view