# macOS app full screen button turns to a plus and enter full screen is disabled

Tags: swift, macos

I am not certain what did I change but the full screen button now turns to a plus `+` instead of expand to full icon. Moreover, the free "Enter Full Screen" menu item in View is also disabled. In other word, the right most standard window button is always a `.zoomButton` but not a full screen button.

[image]

**FAILED**, Manually trigger entering full screen does not work either, [MAC OS Xcode Swift 2.2 Fullscreen Mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164793/mac-os-xcode-swift-2-2-fullscreen-mode)

```
window.toggleFullScreen(self)
```

**FAILED**, Tried to change `collectionBehavior` but had no luck on that either, [OSX - Disable Fullscreen Mode from the zoom button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33457029/osx-disable-fullscreen-mode-from-the-zoom-button)

```
window.collectionBehavior = .fullScreenAuxiliary
```

All code related to window are setting the initial window size and make it can be resized with an aspected ratio, however, disabling those code still won't restore full screen functionality.

```
window = NSWindow(
    contentRect: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 50),
    styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)

window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true

window.contentView?.window?.aspectRatio = NSSize(
    width: 120,
    height: 50
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried a few option in `collectionBehavior` and the setting below works!

```
window.collectionBehavior = .fullScreenPrimary
```