# Enable fullscreen for floating window in macOS app

Tags: swift, macos, nswindow

I set the app windows to floating, to keep them on top:

```
NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
    window.level = .floating
}
```

However, this disables the fullscreen mode:

- The green window button maximizes the window size but doesn't activate fullscreen mode
- The "View" menu "Enter Full Screen" item is disabled

Can these two behaviors (floating windows & fullscreen mode) be enabled in parallel? I have checked project settings and developer docs, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by setting `collectionBehavior`:

```
NSApplication.shared.windows.forEach { window in
    window.collectionBehavior = [.fullScreenPrimary]
    window.level = .floating
}
```

I found [a similar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63506994/macos-app-full-screen-button-turns-to-a-plus-and-enter-full-screen-is-disabled), they also set some properties (not the `level`) of the window, and fullscreen gets disabled.

So is it that if `collectionBehavior` is not specified for an NSWindow, then fullscreen is enabled as long as certain NSWindow properties (e.g. `level`) are not explicitly set?